# How could I prove whether the infinite series $n!/n^n$ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How would you go about proving the infinite series $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges or diverges?

Comment: Do you know the convergence tests?

Comment: I've been trying to use the Comparison test, but haven't made much progress. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Ok. give me a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first use the zero test that states:

$$\sum{a_n} \ \text{diverges if} \lim_{x\to\infty}a_n\neq0.$$

So we test the series and get that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0.$$

By this result, we fail to show that the series diverges, however it is inconclusive. Therefore, we must use another test.

I did this by the ratio test. The test states as follows:

$$\sum{a_n} \ \text{with} \ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} \ \text{where it converges if} \ L<1.$$

So, if we work the series out by this test, we get

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}  \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n} = \frac{1}{e}< 1.$$

In conclusion, since $L<1$, $\sum\frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer nicely done - makes a lot of sense!

Comment: May I ask, "why the downvotes?"

Comment: @JulianRachman "By this result, we can see that the series does not diverge, however it is still inconclusive that the series converges." This is not right at all. The theorem you used gives sufficient conditions for convergence, not necessary. And "converges xor diverges" is a tautology, so the statement itself does not make sense. (edit: it's fixed now, though only the ratio test is necessary, undid -1).

Comment: @Eric it was edited

Answer (score 6):

Since

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}  \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n} = \frac{1}{e}< 1,$$

your series converges by the ratio test.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense. Didn't recognize limit became e! Beautiful!